# Returning same value of array in DB even after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, mysqli

There is an `arr` variable which holds all the time elements which I captured whenever a user pause in a video, but the value of `arr` remains the same every time I refresh the page and even if I perform the activity in another way.

Can someone please tell me why the value is not changing in the database???

Below are HTML file which redirects to PHP file for database connection.

**HTML**

```
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
     <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19/video.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
             integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" 
             crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>

   <body> 
     <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
            preload="none" width="640" height="264" 
            poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup="{}">
       <source src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Ai_Edutech_trial_project\video js\video-js-
                    6.4.0\examples\simple-embed\HTML Tutorial for Beginners - 00 - 
                    Introduction to HTML.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <track kind="captions" src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Ai_Edutech_trial_project\video 
                   js\video-js-6.4.0\examples\simple-embed\HTML Tutorial for Beginners - 00 - 
                   Introduction to HTML [English].vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default>
       <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and 
          consider upgrading to a web browser that 
          <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" 
             target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
       </p>
     </video>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       function ajax_post_one(count, duration, tot_time, arr) {
         // Create our XMLHttpRequest object 
         var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = "my_parse_file_one.php";

         alert(count);
         alert(tot_time);

         var num_pause = count;
         var tt = tot_time;
         var time_arr = arr;
         var dur = duration;
         var vars = "count=" + num_pause + "&tot_time=" + tt +
                    "&arr=" + time_arr + "&duration=" + dur;

         hr.open("POST", url, true);
         hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
             var return_data = hr.responseText;
             document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
           }
         }

         hr.send(vars);
         document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing..."; 
       }

       $(document).ready(function () {
         var player = videojs('example_video_1');
         var pause_t = 0;
         var tot_time = 0;
         var duration = 0;
         var count = 0;
         var arr = new Array();

         player.ready(function () {
           // alert("Working");
         });

         player.on("pause", function () {
           pause_t = player.currentTime();
           tot_time = tot_time + pause_t;
           arr = arr + pause_t;
         });

         player.on("play", function () {});
         player.on("play", function () {
           count = count + 1;
         });

         // This tells the total duration of the video... 
         player.one('loadedmetadata', function () {
           duration = player.duration();
         });

         var video = videojs('example_video_1').ready(function () {
           var player = this;
           player.on('ended', function () {
             alert(tot_time);
             alert(arr);
             ajax_post_one(count, duration, tot_time, arr);
           });
         });
       });
     </script>

     <p> Status down here</p>
     <div id="status"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
   $servername = "localhost"; 
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
   echo "Connected successfully";

   // $db = mysqli_select_db("ajax", $conn);

   // Selecting Database
   mysqli_select_db($conn,"videojs"); 

   //MySQL Query to read datao
   $num_pause =($_POST['count']);
   $tot_time =($_POST['tot_time']);
   $time_arr =($_POST['arr']);
   $duration =($_POST['duration']);

   echo "$num_pause";
   echo "$tot_time";

   $sql = "INSERT INTO info (num_pause, duration, tot_time, time_arr)
   VALUES ('$num_pause', '$tot_time','$duration','$time_arr')";
   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: is it spitting out the error message from sql?

Comment: no error message, the "arr" variable is storing correct value which can be seen on alert message and correct value to php file too where i used echo to check but in database its value is constant for every event.

Comment: try changing arr= arr +pause_t; to arr.push(pause_t);

Comment: it changes the value to 1 in database on any event performed is there some mistake that i have declared... var arr = new Array(); outside the pause function ?????

Answer (score 0):

I think you have bug with your php, for update some data from DB, use "UPDATE", not "INSERT". you can use jquery $.post for POST request, convenient. for test php code feeding different data directly from browser console

```
var address = './my_parse_file_one.php';
var data = {count:11, tot_time:11, arr:11, duration:11};
$.post(address, data, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: no it updates all the value of my database and still the value of "arr" remain the same...     :(